# You have ran out of Application Memory, even after restart

Tags: memory, osx-mavericks, memory-leaks

My Mac running maveriks updated recently is getting a Application memory error I have taking a screenshot with the activity monitor running in the background and the error in front

[image]

Comment: This error is happening apon multiple restarts.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I use Firefox 99% of the time and safari the rest of the time. I opened activity monitor. I opened Firefox. After about 2-3 minutes my ram was at 7.99 g. I have a total of 8. I got the same results with safari. I completely uninstalled Firefox. I downloaded Firefox and reinstalled it. MAGIC. All the problems went away and the computer is very fast again. Ram usage is steady at 3.2 no longer 7.99. I don't know why and don't care, but it seems to be fixed